# Cookie and Authorization or authentication not forwarding in spring microservices

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes, keycloak, kubernetes-ingress

I have created 2 microservices one using spring-cloud-gateway and one for the Keycloak authentication. So when client tries to access gateway application it redirects it to the Keycloak login page and after login keycloak application redirects it again to the Gateway application.

Normally it is working fine but when we deployed it inside Kubernetes it stopped working our application started on http but via ingres we are accessing it in https.

So when client try to access https://gateway it is redirecting to keycloak login page but after login it is again re-directing to the gateway application but Cookies and Authorization are headers are not set or missing we can see them till redirection but not after that.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/security")
public RedirectView sendRequestToSPM(HttpServletRequest sp, @RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers, @PathVariable String name,
                                     @RequestParam(required = false, name = "redirectUri", defaultValue = "") String redirectUri) {
    try {
        Map<String, Object> heads = new HashMap<>();

        headers.entrySet().forEach(j -> {
            System.out.println("Headers Key: " + j.getKey() + " Headers Value: " + j.getValue());
            heads.put(j.getKey(), j.getValue().get(0));
        });

        System.out.println("Cookie Ganied: " + sp.getSession().getId());

         // Here session and cookie came in header both are different why?

    
            return new RedirectView("https://gateway/sso_login?e=" + data);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

This the code where I redirect it from security to gateway after login but it is not passing the headers?

And this is Ingress:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: apps
  name: gateway
  labels:
    app: gateway
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-prod"
    acme.cert-manager.io/http01-edit-in-place: "true"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: gateway
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: gateway
            port:
              number: 9001
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - 'gateway'
    secretName: gateway-tls
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: apps
  name: security
  labels:
    app: security
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-prod"
    acme.cert-manager.io/http01-edit-in-place: "true"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: security
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: security
            port:
              number: 9000
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - 'security'
    secretName: security-tls
```

I think request context is getting different, please can help will be really helpful.